# Difference between Likelihood and Probability in this scenerio?

Tags: bayesian

Lets say we have 100 people.

10 of them wear red.

20 wear blue.

70 wear green.

20 people from this group wear glasses.

We know that 3 people in the red group wear glasses and five people in the green group wear glasses. This means the other 12 who wear glasses are in the green group.

If I was blindfolded and selected one person from the red group, what is the probability I will select a person with glasses?

If I was blindfolded and selected one person from the red group, what is the likelihood the person I selected will be wearing glasses?

If all three groups were combined and I selected one person while blindfolded, what is the probability and likelihood of selecting a red person with glasses?

Also, how can I calculate this in excel?

Comment: Can you rephrase your questions? Because probability that the red group will have someone who wears glasses will be surely $1$ since we know that there are people who wear glasses in the red group.

Comment: OK, I see that now. I reworded it. I think this is more of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, I don't see a difference between the following two questions:

- What is the *probability* of getting heads if you toss a fair coin?
- What is the *likelihood* of getting heads if you toss a fair coin?

So, the answer to your first and second questions will be the same:
$$P(\text{Selected One is with Glasses|Selected one is from Red Group})=P(G|R)=\frac{P(R\cap G)}{P(R)}=\frac{3}{10}$$

The third and fourth questions, we simply seek for $P(R\cap G)=\frac{3}{100}$

In Excel, it's just a matter of assigning cells to each of these probabilities, and applying the formulas.

There are some other uses of the keyword *likelihood* together with other keywords like *posterior*, *prior*, *evidence* etc. although your question doesn't seem to go that much deep.